# Trouble setting up permissions for jailed SFTP user

Tags: ssh, arch-linux, sftp, chmod, chroot

I'm running Arch and have created a new user named moderator that I would like to give access to a couple of folders that they can read / write to.

My plan was to create a new folder, named "mod", and I would symlink the 2 folders that they can access there.

Then, I want to limit their access in SFTP to that "mod" folder. I found this online and tried adding it to /etc/ssh/sshd_config:

```
Match User moderator
    ChrootDirectory /mod
    ForceCommand internal-sftp
    AllowTcpForwarding no
    X11Forwarding no
    PasswordAuthentication yes
```

However, this did not work. When I attempted to connect on various SFTP clients, they reported "software caused connection abort"

When I checked the logs, it said it accepted the password, opened the connection, then immediately closed it, with no real error. If I were to delete those lines I just added, I can connect to the root folder perfectly fine. So when looking this up, it looks like its a folder permission error, however, I'm a little hesitant to chmod anything, because I've had some things get screwed up royally in the past doing that, so I'd really like to double check I'm not going to break anything. Could somebody please help me verify if that is really the problem, and if so, how to set permissions so that "moderator" user can read/write to their jailed folder?

Thanks for any help

EDIT: The permissions of the directory are:

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 moderator moderator 4096 Oct 16 10:25 /drives/xerxes/mods
```

Comment: Please run "ls -ld /mod" to display permissions and ownership on this "/mod" directory, then [edit] your question to include the information.

Comment: I have updated the question